# How should I add a field containing a list of dictionaries in Marshmallow Python?

Tags: python, nested, marshmallow, data-class

In `Marshmallow` in order to have a list field you can use:

```
include_in = fields.List(cls_or_instance=fields.Str(),
                         default=['sample1', 'sample2'])
```

This is OK, but I have a new requirement to have a list of dictionaries in a field. A sample payload:

```
[{
  "name": "Ali",
  "age": 20
},
{
  "name": "Hasan",
  "age": 32
}]
```

This payload is part of the bigger schema, **so now the question is** how should I add and validate such a field?

---

**EDIT-1:**
I went a step further and could find out that there is a `Dict` field type in `Marshmallow` so until now I have the below code sample:

```
fields.List(fields.Dict(
        keys=fields.String(validate=OneOf(('name', 'age'))),
        values=fields.String(required=True)
))
```

Now new problem arise and I cannot set different data types for fields in the dictionary (`name` and `age`). I'd be happy if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: You may want to look into https://github.com/Bachmann1234/marshmallow-polyfield or https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-oneofschema, which both implement polymorphic fields, i.e. you can use a different schemas for different data shapes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the items in the list have the same shape, you can use a nested field within `fields.List`, like so:

```py
class PersonSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    age = fields.Int()

class RootSchema(Schema):
    people = fields.List(fields.Nested(PersonSchema))
```

Comment: Something like ```people = fields.List(fields.Nested(PersonSchema()))``` also works in my case

Answer (score 2):

Another approach for validating list of dictionaries in a field using one schema class.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, ValidationError


class PeopleSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    age = fields.Int(required=True)


people = [{
    "name": "Ali",
    "age": 20
},
{
    "name": "Hasan",
    "age": 32
},
{
    "name": "Ali",
    "age": "twenty"  # Error: Not an int
}
]


def validate_people():
    try:
        validated_data = PeopleSchema(many=True).load(people)
    except ValidationError as err:
        print(err.messages)

validate_people()
```

Output:

```
{2: {'age': ['Not a valid integer.']}}
```