# Unable to validate list of dicts using marshmallow Schema with webargs use_kwargs - Error 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow, http-status-code-422, webargs

I have the following endpoint in `Flask`:

```py
from flask import Flask
from marshmallow import EXCLUDE, Schema, fields
from webargs.flaskparser import use_kwargs

app = Flask(
    __name__, static_url_path="", static_folder="static", template_folder="templates"
)


class Measure(Schema):
    type = fields.Int(required=True)
    value = fields.Float(required=True)
    unit = fields.Int(required=True)
    date = fields.Int(required=True)


class RequestSchema(Schema):
    measures = fields.List(fields.Nested(Measure))


@app.route("/save", methods=["POST"])
@use_kwargs(
    RequestSchema,
    location="json_or_form",
    unknown=EXCLUDE,
)
def save(**measures):
    return {"foo": measures}, 200
```

With `pytest`, I test the following:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def app():
    test_app = AppClientPublic()
    return test_app.app

def test_save(app):
    measures = [
        {
            "type": 1,
            "value": 2.2,
            "unit": 3,
            "date": 4,
        },
        {
            "type": 5,
            "value": 6.6,
            "unit": 7,
            "date": 8,
        },
    ]
    r = app.post(
        "/save",
        data={"measures": measures},
    )
    assert r.status_code == 200
```

I get the following error:

> Error 422 Unprocessable Entity: The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors. - {'messages': {'json_or_form': {'measures': {0: {'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}, 1: {'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}}}}, 'schema': <RequestSchema(many=False)>, 'headers': None}

However, if I validate the same dictionary directly:

```
d = {
    "measures": [
        {
            "type": 1,
            "value": 2.2,
            "unit": 3,
            "date": 4,
        },
        {
            "type": 5,
            "value": 6.6,
            "unit": 7,
            "date": 8,
        },
    ]
}

req_schema = RequestSchema()
errors = req_schema.validate(d)
print(errors)  # {} -> no errors
```

I get no validation error.

I also have absolutely no problem validating simple objects like just a depth-1 dictionary, but I am unable to validate a list of `Measure` on the Flask endpoint.

What am I doing wrong?

**PS:**

- I am aware of [How should I add a field containing a list of dictionaries in Marshmallow Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966172/how-should-i-add-a-field-containing-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-marshmallow-python). It works fine. My problem is more focused on why it does not work when using it in `use_kwargs` on the Flask endpoint.
- The different versions:

  - Python 3.8
  - Flask 2.1.3
  - marshmallow 3.17.0
  - webargs 8.2.0

Comment: Does it work with "location=json"? (

Comment: (it shouldn't make any difference but I see no reason for your code to fail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the `pytest` side, not the `Flask` side.

I changed the `post` call to use `json` instead of `data`:

```
r = app.post("/save", json={"measures": measures})
# instead of 
r = app.post("/save", data={"measures": measures})
```